# No titles in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

Please have a look at the following code

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Table extends JFrame
{
    private JTable table;

    public Table()
    {

        String[] columnNames = {"first name","last name","address"};
        Object[][]data = {{"John","Kane","NY"},{"Nayomi","Writz","NY"}};

        table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

        getContentPane().add(table);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);


    }

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Table();
    }
}
```

I haven't used JTable before, so this is my first attempt. In here, it is not showing the column names, just showing the data. Why is that? Please help!

Comment: reading the tutorial referenced in the swing tag description will spare you a lot of frustration :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put it in a `JScrollPane` or similar.

See the top of the API docs for `JTable`, and `JScrollPane`.

Comment: extremely sorry for the massive delay. Thanks a lot for the help!